# Date API: Proper method of parsing dates

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm working on a simple event sign up module. The functionality is split in two modules, one which provides an Event content type with title, description and date (from - to) fields, and the second with sign up functionality and sign up window dates for Event content type. The problem is that I don't seem to find a way to properly parse and do comparisons and calculations on the event/signup dates.

Date API documention is quite light on specifics on this area, so it has not been much of a help.

- How can I use the Date API to obtain DateObject from the event date stored on the node?
- How can I determine whether the stored event is an all day event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the Date API to obtain DateObject from the event date
>   stored on the node?

Offhand, I'm not 100% sure the right way to do this. It sounds like you want to use the DateObject to perform some calculations -- not just to run through a theme field_formatter. This [date issue thread](http://drupal.org/node/1108164) has some code kinda trying to use date fields and their values, but doesnt help much.

Simply because I can understand it (and have used this module myself) I recommend trying out the sub-module of Date, date_api, and an additional 3rd party module: [field_extract](http://www.drupal.org/project/field_extract).

With field extract you can easily (and correctly) access a fields value for instance [as a timestamp](http://drupalcode.org/project/1158878.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/field_extract/includes/date.inc#l42):

```
  // Extract from a date, this extracts the first value and provides a
  // formatted date output, uses the specified format, by name.
  $event_timestamp = field_extract_value('node', $node, 'field_event_time', 0, array('format' => 'timestamp'));
```

You can then use the DateAPI to create a [DateObject](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob/b7502f3a86628e5c4995c01f20ac64d5cee5888b:/date_api/date_api.module#l143):

```
$date = new DateObject($event_timestamp);
```

> How can I determine whether the stored event is an
>   all day event?

Use the [date_is_all_day()](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob/b7502f3a86628e5c4995c01f20ac64d5cee5888b:/date_api/date_api.module#l2562) function found in the date_api module, it compares 2 date fields to check if they encompass a full day.

```
 function date_is_all_day($string1, $string2, $granularity = 'second', $increment = 1) { ... }
```